# Is there a way to enforce javascript code is executed before launching a synchronous ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, execution

I don't really know what i'm doing wrong here. I got some javascript (with jQuery) that go like this:

```
function myFunc(){
    $('.wait').addClass('waiting');
    console.log('wait');
    var r = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "my_URL", async: false}).responseText;
    $('.wait').removeClass('waiting');
    console.log('stop wait');
    return r;
}
```

My problem is that the class "waiting" is not added while doing this call... What I mean is that  when I call my function, I got a div that is supposed to be appear at the beginning and then be remove after but it doesn't show up. 
Everything seem to be proceeding accordingly. I got the result of my ajax call, when I tried to execute it without the

```
$('.wait').removeClass('waiting');
```

My div show up **but only after I got the ajax response**... I tried to time the request and it take approximately **2 second**... so I don't really know why this is happening.

Could it be related to the synchronous ajax call? Since JavaScript is a procedural language, I thought that the addition of the class should be done before logging into the console and before starting the ajax call, but I got all the modification after I got the response (even in the JavaScript console, everything append after the ajax call).

Any help would be really nice!

Comment: why sync call why not async???

Comment: You don't see any visible change because you are making a synchronous call. You don't give the browser the chance to do a reflow.

Comment: I use sync because it is a verification method, I got multiple user editing a file an when they make a modification I don't want them to overwrite something. So I freeze the page to be sure somebody didn't modify something in the meen time...

Comment: it will not stop other user will it??

Comment: Is there a way to force a reflow to the browser?

Comment: It will not stop other user but i will be able to reload the page before they do a modification...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens in the browser while the function is running, so you need to use asynchronous code so that the browser can update the element. You can use the `setTimeout` method to run rest of the code after the browser has had a chance to update.

As the code is asynchronous you can't return the value from the function, as the function exists before the AJAX call is made. Use a callback function to get the value:

```
function myFunc(callback){
  $('.wait').addClass('waiting');
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    var r = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "my_URL", async: false}).responseText;
    $('.wait').removeClass('waiting');
    callback(r);
  }, 0);
}
```

As you have to use asynchronous code to update the element, you can just as well make the AJAX call asynchronous, that keeps the browser from being unresponsive during the request:

```
function myFunc(callback){
  $('.wait').addClass('waiting');
  $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "my_URL", success: function(data){
    $('.wait').removeClass('waiting');
    callback(data);
  }});
}
```

Comment: I think I will go your way even if it will take a lot of time to refactor everything... Thank for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here you go async version. You should pass callback function that will be called with result thought. That `return data` is wrong in given circumstances.

```
function myFunc() {
    $('.wait').addClass('waiting');
    console.log('wait');
    var r = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "my_URL",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $('.wait').removeClass('waiting');
            console.log('stop wait');
            return data;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use async version, I got a lot of function doing stuff that call mine at the start and then proceed by thinking the call has been done...